# ScrollView causes buggy buttons in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, scrollview, swiftui

I've been trying to create a form in SwiftUI but because of the limitations using "Form()" I instead chose to create a ScrollView with a ForEach loop that contains a button. When I run the project and I try to click on the buttons it clicks the incorrect one, unless I scroll the view. I am new in SwiftUI and I have not been able to figure it out.

I tried making the ScrollView in different sizes and it doesn't seem to be related

```
struct DropDown: View {

var datos: [String]
var categoria: String

@State var titulo: String = "Seleccione"
@State var expand = false

var body: some View {

    VStack {
        Text(categoria).fontWeight(.heavy).foregroundColor(.white)
        HStack {
            Text(titulo).fontWeight(.light).foregroundColor(.white)
            Image(systemName: expand ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.down").resizable().frame(width: 10, height: 6).foregroundColor(.white)

        }.onTapGesture {
            self.expand.toggle()
        }

        if expand {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: true) {
                ForEach(0..<self.datos.count){ nombre in
                    Button(action: {
                        print(self.datos[nombre])
                        self.titulo = self.datos[nombre]
                        self.expand.toggle()
                        diccionarioDatos[self.categoria] = self.titulo
                        print(diccionarioDatos)
                    }) {
                        Text(self.datos[nombre]).foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: 150)
            .fixedSize()
        }
    }
    .padding()
    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [.blue, .green]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
    .cornerRadius(20)
    .animation(.spring())
}
```

}

[I clicked on "2018" under "Modelo" and "2015" got selected for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s4Yf.jpg)

[This is how the dropdown menu looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCq4V.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean it clicks the incorrect button? Does the wrong button highlight? The wrong date prints to the console? Some more context may be helpful to find the solution.

Comment: When I try to select a button from the drop down it presses a different one, usually is the first one in the list.

Comment: Adding the code for the parent view may be helpful? The only thing I can suggest is to double check the frame of the button text and see if it is as you expect.

Comment: Done, can you try to check it again... Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I tested the observed behaviour is due to order of animatable properties. In your case moving rounding corners into background itself solves the problem.

So instead of

```swift
.background(
    LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [.blue, .green]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
)
.cornerRadius(20)
```

Use

```swift
.background(
    LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [.blue, .green]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
        .cornerRadius(20)
)
```

Comment: Why did the modifier on the VStack cause problems? Were the buttons being laid out strangely?

Comment: This is actually correct, adding .animation(nil) fixed the issue for me

Comment: Excellent answer. It was my problem aswell for all Scrollviews with Buttons loaded by a ForEach. In my case the Parent had CornerRadius, and each button has CornerRadius, moving CornerRadius into the .background attribute worked.

Comment: ??? Not sure what’s going on with all your answers right now?

Comment: Just spent hours trying to debug a similar issue. Moving the `.clipShape()` to the background worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `.onTapGesture` instead of `action` for the buttons.

```
Button(action: {}, label: {
    Text(self.datos[nombre]).foregroundColor(.white)
}).onTapGesture{
    print(self.datos[nombre])
    self.titulo = self.datos[nombre]
    self.expand.toggle()
    diccionarioDatos[self.categoria] = self.titulo
    print(diccionarioDatos)
}
```

Comment: onTapGesture does not get called with empty button action any more (Xcode 11.3.1)